# Problem with creating page for the path of page display of a view

Tags: 7, views, theming

I created a *library* content type. Its view is *library__view*; this view has a page display whose path is *library*, which has a contextual filter on the subject of the books(e.g. math, physics).

I created a page in my theme folder, and renamed it *page--library.tpl.php*. I also embedded library__view using this line.

```
views_embed_view('library__view','page');
```

The problem is that *library/math* does not show math books (while it works right in the view administrative menu).

What is wrong with this? What is the filename of a view whose path is specified to be in a certain URL (e.g. page--library.tpl.php, library.tpl.php)?

Comment: "library/math does not show math books" so what it shows? Error message? Empty result set? And is it empty when you're logged in as admin? Is it a matter of filter? View without filter works OK?

Comment: have tried with some other path ?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are embedding a view in a custom page tpl instead of just creating a page view and assigning it the path of library? You shouldn't need a custom tpl file at all for this.

Comment: @rooby this is exactly my problem, I don't know how to create a page view

Comment: @Mołot it shows page--library.tpl.php page

Comment: @Bala yes I have

Comment: @Mohammed: You said in your question that you have already created a page view. All you do is create a view with a page display and it does the rest. The if you enter the path as library the view will magically be at example.com/library and your contextual filters will allow you to do things like example.com/library/math. There is no need for any coding.

Comment: @rooby i think there is a problem with the name of file which I embedded the view inside it

Comment: @Mohammad Is is your problem resolved?

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal NO I replied your comment

Comment: From what you are describing you should not need any template file. Try deleting the template file, clearing the cache, making sure the page view is set to use the path library, and then go tho that path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I infer: you have created the view for listing the contents of **library** content type, now you are embedding that view in the page template file for theming the contents listed on the page created by view. If this is the case than you are doing the things in incorrect way.

Possible cases for creating the template file for views page:
**1.** Theme the contents rendered by **views** on `http://www.yourdomain.com/library` page: For this you need to create template file as per the [views template suggestion](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/group/views_templates/7), also its best to create the template for view from the suggestion generated by view at **Theme: Information** as below:

[image]
The suggestions for creating the template in the below image is based upon the "test-contact" page I have created in views:
[image]

**2.** Theming the content created for **library** content type: If you want to theme the contents that is rendered while creating a nodes of `library` type than you need to create the `node--library.tpl.php`. This template will be just for theming the contents of `library` content type created originally (not for the content listed on `library` page created from views) and it wont have any impact on your views page.

> Now coming to your issue of page at `library/math' does not show math books:

- Check if the result in your created view displayed correctly (to confirm that the contextual filter is working fine) on passing `math` as argument to "Preview with contextual filters" (present at bottom of view).
- Make sure that the path of page that you are creating from view is
  `/library`, and for testing purpose you can try changing the path
  temporarily to `/library123` (If changing the path, than test the
  result at `yourdomain.com/library123/math` page)
- Remove the template you have created for embedding the view (as it doesn't seems to be needed, at least as of now)
- Clear the cache and check again (not needed logically but no problem for testing purpose)

Comment: I created *views-view--library__view--page.tpl* and I found that the embedded view inside *page--library* was rendered through this .ok it is good but here is a problem; page--library is just a page and can have multiple views that are embedded inside it,right?so if I add /math after its url how does drupal understand that /math belongs to *library__view*?so I deleted page--library and expected that I could see output of *views-view--library__view--page.tpl* when I visit **/library** page, but I just saw my page.tpl.php .I guess library__view must be somehow embedded some where

Comment: @Mohammad Have you cleared the cache of site, and one more thing I am not getting is why are you trying to embed the view in template file. Also drupal will automatically take care of the arguments you pass on `/library` page, can you once try and check

Comment: Yes I have, because I don't know how to output views on their path (what file I must create to display views on their specified path? what is its name?) , the only way I know is to embed them! like I said I created **views-view--library__view--page.tpl ** page and wrote <?php print 'hello'?> inside of it, but when I visited /library page I saw my page.tpl.php ! it means views-view--library__view--page.tpl was not rendered.

Comment: @Mohammad Ok, That I was guessing and I have mentioned in my answer also. So If you want to output the view on their path i.e `library` than no need to create any template file for it, drupal will automatically render the view at `library` page once you created it from views UI. So now remove any custom template file you have created for checking the output of view and than check the result of `library` page (after clearing the cache). Let me know if problem doesnt get resolved

Comment: I tried this and it didn't display library content; but fortunately I found a solution for contextual filter problem and i sent arguments to views_embed_view() and drupal treated these arguments as contextual filter, so the problem solved. but it is still wondering me why /path does not work!

Comment: @Mohammad if you are getting the content `library/math`  page correctly, and no content of `library` page than you have to do a little modification in your contextual filter to display all contents when no context is found

Comment: I set drupal setting to if there is no contextual filter then display all the items

Comment: @Mohammad So now it must be showing all items, right?

Comment: yes it shows all items